# Javascript direction (forward backward) buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript forward backward buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238734/javascript-forward-backward-buttons)

Hello,

I'm using the s3Slider javascript slideshow on the homepage of a site I am developing:

http://alexisparkinn.com/

I really like this slideshow but it has no way to enable the user to go to the next or previous image.

How can I add these buttons?  Does anybody know the necessary javascript code I need to use or what changes should be made.

Suggestions?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!