# Javascript forward backward buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the s3Slider javascript slideshow on the homepage of a site I am developing:

http://alexisparkinn.com/

I really like this slideshow but it has no way to enable the user to go to the next or previous image.

How can I add these buttons? Does anybody know the necessary javascript code I need to use or what changes should be made.

Suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The functions are defined private in the slider script.

Comment: Do you want the slideshow to stop when you click these buttons?

Comment: No, I just want people to be able to move forward and backward to their liking.  Should I upload the javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't ask for suggestions, but let me just throw this out there as a solution:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

After messing around with a ton of sliders, I've ended up going back to this one time after time. (and there is a 4KB version if all you want is the fade effect)

It has pretty decent documentation and is overall pretty easy and straightforward to use.

Anyway, just wanted to throw that out there. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks! Those are some sweet sliders.  I'll be sure to implement some of them in future work.  Your suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @toddsler. I came here to see how to get s3slider to work for me, and within minutes had cycle up and running. They just add the much needed method to jquery. Simple and easy to use. Make sure to read the tutorial for "beginners" at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to hack something in, I'd modify your s3slider copy to include something like this (insert at line 38)

```
$(element).bind("s3slidernext", function() {
   current = items[currNo+1];
   fadeElement(false);
});
```

Then you can probably just call

```
$('#s3slider').trigger("s3slidernext");
```

To move the slider forward. Bind that to a button and you're all set.

Comment: Hey Josh I've put this in my code.  The first bit I put on line 38 of my s3slider.js page and the other I put in the head section of my index page.  How do I make the next/previous arrows show up?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll need to make some buttons and probably use .bind() to call the $('#s3slider').trigger("s3slidernext"); bit.

Answer (score 0):

there are many jquery libraries that can help you out there like http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/